# Split date variable into components

Tags: string, bash, split

I have a string from a log that's the equivelent of this....

a="20131202"

I need to seperate it out in to the 3 components.

I am assuming sed is the tool

Can I get a little guidance?

Answer (score 4):

Parameter expansion is a better tool:

```
a=20131202
year=${a:0:4}
month=${a:4:2}
day=${a:6:2}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to cut string, things like ${a:0:4} is good enough.

Or you may want to know something else:
Use date command:

```
a="20131202"
declare -a A=($(date -d $a +"%Y %m %d"));
echo ${A[0]}, ${A[1]}, ${A[2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using regular expressions:

```
[[ $a =~ (....)(..)(..) ]]
year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

Comment: This is what I would do and should be faster than calling out to `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sed for this.
You can use this syntax :

```
echo ${a:0:4} # print 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested in using sed, this will work with the example you provided:

```
yes a=\"20131202\" | sed -e :a -e 's/...\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)./\1 \2 \3/'
```